# android, target SDK 23, permissions at runtime returns true when it shouldn't

Tags: android, google-maps, sdk, permissions

I've got some problems with checking permissions at runtime in Android, where target SDK is 23. Here's some of my code in my main activity.

```
       public void GoToLocation(){
                if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION);
                }
                else {
                    locationManager= (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                    Location locator = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    LatLng position = new LatLng(locator.getLatitude(), locator.getLongitude());

                    Marker m = myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(position));
                    mapsMarkers.add(m);

                    myMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(position, 6));
                }
            }
```

The thing is: this method is invoked by users's click on the map. I don't know why, but first `if` returns `false` (which means that permissions were granted altough they weren't!). So it goes to the `else` clause and it throws a null refference exception, cause locator gets `null` (since I never gave those permissions, `requestMethod()` hadn't had chancess to be invoked).

I've followed [this](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html), yet seems like I did some mistake.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: where you are testing your code ? In any marshmallow device ? Please check the granted permisson of the app from settings. If permissions are granted then off the permission and again test the app.

Answer (score 0):

try this ;

```
  public void GoToLocation(){
            if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION);
            }
            else {
                locationManager= (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                Location locator = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                LatLng position = new LatLng(locator.getLatitude(), locator.getLongitude());

                Marker m = myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(position));
                mapsMarkers.add(m);

                myMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(position, 6));
            }
        }
```

Make sure u test this in device running marshmallow or higher